# Proper response when random "Pages" circle you on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages, google-plus-circles

On a regular basis, I get notifications that some Google+ page has added me to their circles.

- I can understand why a stranger (a *person*) would circle me, but **why is a *page* circling me?**
- These pages are never relevant to me so I always block them, just to be safe. **What is a proper reaction?**

*Update:* I'm aware that a page always "circles me back" if I circle it, but that's not the case here -- I've never heard of them before they circled me. I'm guessing that perhaps the page manager finds my stream interesting but it's more likely to be a spam job.

Comment: If I recall, a Page can't circle you unless you circle it. Could these be spoofed messages?

Comment: I didn't circle those pages. Perhaps they're really fake "people" and that's how they can circle me. I'll consider that next time, and report the user if appropriate.

Comment: Why bother blocking them? It's not a big deal to do, but what does it matter who is following you? You are in no way obligated to circle/follow them back.

Comment: Just ignore them unless they start bothering you with spam.

Answer (score 1):

It is proper to do nothing and let them circle you. Think of it like Twitter when a brand follows you; it's not a problem. I would not block them as standard practice (only block and/or report when appropriate).